# Find word and hide using xslt

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, rss

I have an RSS viewer webpart inserted on a page (Sharepoint 2010).

In that, one of the feeds contains Discuss word which is "hyperlink" (which goes to the feed site) which I have to remove.

This Word resides in feeds description. thus can not not select this single word in SPD.

Any idea how to find this word and hide or remove it, using XSLT?

Comment: Your question is as yet difficult to answer. Please include your input XML, describe the changes you'd like to make and show any attemped XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: I do not have raw xml file. RSS feed's description is being displayed on SharePoint page.In that description there is a "Discuss" word  in the end. so I want to hide/remove that word.

Comment: If you cannot find an actual XML source you prevent users without knowledge of Sharepoint and RSS from helping you. You can see the URL of RSS feeds in Sharepoint, right? Have you opened it in a browser and looked at the source?

Answer (score 0):

To find a single word<sup>(*)</sup> in a string of text you can use XPath like this:

```
description[
  contains(
    concat(' ', normalize-space(.), ' '), ' hyperlink '
  )
]
```

<sup>(*)</sup> where *"word"* means *"string of non-space characters that is delimited by spaces on both sides"*

Note the extra spaces that prevent false positives and allow matching word instances at the start or the end of the string.

You might want to replace punctuation with space to aid finding the word:

```
description[
  contains(
    concat(' ', normalize-space(translate(., ',.()"!?-', '        ')), ' '), 
    ' hyperlink '
  )
]
```

After that you can replace it by using a combination of `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`

```
concat(substring-before(., 'hyperlink'), substring-after(., 'hyperlink'))
```

You might want to use this as part of a recursive template if the word can occur more than once in the string.

There are [several examples of "string-replace" XSLT templates on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22string-replace%22%20%5Bxslt%5D) that show how to do this.